# Analysis:Is $x|x|$ differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I plotted this graph in wolfram alpha and it looks nice and smooth at $x=0$.  Does that mean that $x|x|$ is differentiable at $x=0$?  I don't understand formally using the definition of the derivative why this is the case.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. But its second derivative does not exist at $0$

Comment: "I don't understand formally using the definition of the derivative why this is the case. " Why? What's difficult in writing down the definition?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I was overthinking it.  I understand  now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because the graph looks nice and smooth that the function is differentiable, although that is what the term is trying to capture.

The function is differentiable because of the **definition** of differentiable.  The limit
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h|h|}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} |h| = 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)=x|x|$ can be written as:

$$f(x)=\cases{ x^2 & $x\ge 0$\\ -x^2 & $x<0$}$$

The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, and the derivative of $-x^2$ is $-2x$. Both approach $0$ as $x\to 0$, and we also have $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}|h|=0$, so $f'(x)$ is defined and continuous at $x=0$. The second derivative however, as noted in a comment above, is problematic...

Answer (score 2):

A more "applied-math" approach is use the formula $$\frac{d|x|}{dx}=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$$ for real $x$. Then we have

$$\frac{d(x|x|)}{dx}=|x|+x\,\mathrm{sgn}(x)=2|x|.$$

The first-order derivative is continuous and equals $\,0\,$ at $\,x=0$. The second-order derivative is $2\,\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ and is not continuous at $\,x=0$.

Comment: One has to be careful with this approach.  $\frac{d|x|}{x} = \mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}(x)$ only when $x\neq 0$, unless we extend the definition of derivative.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, you're right. Also, "derivative not exist" is not the same thing as "derivative not continuous". That's why I say it's "applied-math".